# make a form non interactive when another open c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

i open a form on button click and the first one remain **opened** also.
I want the form below to be **non interactive**.
Means if user click on the form below he should be unable to.
I used topmost property but it doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `Form.ShowDialog` method to open a modal form:

```
using (MyForm frm = new MyForm())
    frm.ShowDialog();
```